# Plotting several grids with labels in a legend

Tags: python, plot, legend, pyvista

I have several meshes I read each of them using pyvista

```
import pyvista as pv

# read the data
grid1 = pv.read('mesh1.vtk')
grid2 = pv.read('mesh2.vtk')
```

I want to plot them together on same plot having different colors
I do :

```
plotter = pv.Plotter(window_size=(1500, 1100))
plotter.add_mesh(grid1, color=[0.6, 0.2, 0.1])
plotter.add_mesh(grid2, color=[0.1, 0.6, 0.6])
```

Can I add label for each grid? or add legend?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this can naturally be done, and you already know the keywords you have to use: `label` and `legend`:

```py
import pyvista as pv 
from pyvista import examples 
 
unstructured = examples.load_hexbeam() 
poly = examples.load_ant() 
poly.points /= 10 
poly.points += [0, 2, 3] 
 
plotter = pv.Plotter() 
plotter.add_mesh(unstructured, color=[0.6, 0.2, 0.1], label='beamy')
plotter.add_mesh(poly, color=[0.1, 0.6, 0.6], label='anty') 
 
plotter.add_legend() 
plotter.show()
```

[image: Plot with a beam and an ant, both with their labels in a legend]

As you can see the strings passed as the `label` keyword argument of `add_mesh` turn into labels in a legend which you can enable with the `add_legend()` call. For customization options of the legend [see the documentation](https://docs.pyvista.org/api/plotting/_autosummary/pyvista.Plotter.add_legend.html#pyvista.Plotter.add_legend).