# PyVista Scale Bar to show object size

Tags: python, pyvista

I want to add a scale bar to show the 3D object size scales the same way with the object, when the user zooms in/out. However the default scale bar of pyvista sticks to the screen that won't move (which is indeed a color bar).
I dug somewhere else [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68811399/pyvista-axes-at-origin-without-scaling), but it seems nobody answered.
I tried drawing a 3D line as below, so that its size won't change, but this line behaves weirdly (moving not the same angular velocity when rotating the camera):

```
from pyvista import examples
plane = examples.load_airplane()
plotter = pv.Plotter(notebook=False)
line = pv.Line((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 20))  # serves as a scale bar with fixed length for object size calibration
plotter.add_mesh(line)
plotter.add_mesh(plane)
plotter.show()
```

Comment: If by "the default scale bar" you mean the _scalar_ bar, that's not supposed to move at all. The purpose of the scalar bar is to indicate what values colours represent in the figure. So it's better to think of it as a _color_ bar. The reason why it's called a scalar bar is because colouring is done by scalar values as data. Running your snippet above it seems to me that the line does indeed "move at the same angular velocity". But it's fairly far from the plane which is why perspective makes it look like it's moving faster. Using `pv.Line((800, 400, 0), (800, 400, 20))` puts it a lot closer.

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні, Thanks for replying, that's my point. 1) I don't want the color bar but a scale bar literally. 2) I figured out that if it's far away, the rotating speed depends on the position you click. I think it's because the two objects rotate each other with respect to the relative mouse position

Comment: The camera always rotates around the focal point. You can try different interactor styles e.g. `plotter.enable_terrain_style()` that will keep "up" pointing "up". At the end of the day you already have what you want: a line that has a specified length, which transforms along with the rest of the scene. If you want a line that has a fixed position in the viewport but scales when you zoom: I don't know how to do that and I wouldn't be surprised if it were impossible (or very difficult) to pull off.

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні interesting, the bar is still moving. The `Line` will rotate with the camera direction, whereas the `Cylinder` no. Your `enable_terrain_styles()` doesn't work. You can write a solution with Cylinder and I will accept it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following. I exactly said that the line will rotate together with the scene. The terrain style was just a suggestion that might give you more intuitive control over the camera. And I don't know what cylinder you're talking about, or why it should behave differently from a line.

Comment: Because I want the scale bar and my object stay fixed one to the other like https://stackoverflow.com/a/63145087/9217178. So a small work around will be replacing the `Line` by `Cylinder`

Comment: OK, that's what I keep saying: _your `Line` is already fixed to the same relative position as your plane_. The line already does what you want. It's always in the same spatial coordinates, so if the plane is also in the same spatial coordinates then they don't move with respect to one another. I cannot phrase this any differently. The issue you seem to try to solve is not there with your `Line`.

Comment: I think https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkLegendScaleActor.html is what is being looked for, which isn't yet supported in pyvista

Comment: More flexible would be to use https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkAxisActor2D.html#details, which is also not supported directly

Comment: Reading this all again, I'm still confused on the ask.  If the question is about an object that has a fixed size and position in world coordinates (the coordinates of the mesh objects themselves), then either Line or Cylinder works.  Note that this means the object will rotate and scale in the view.  If the question is about an object that has a fixed size in world coordinates (it changes apparent size when zoomed) but stays in a fixed orientation in the view (it doesn't rotate in the view), then my suggestions will work once implemented.